# How to retrieve data from MS Access and assign to repeater control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to fetch data from MS Access and assign it to a repeater control. I used the following code and it works well:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\\Joshua_WEB_be.mdb; Persist Security Info=False;");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand myComd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEvents", con);       
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(myComd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

but I want to display the day and month from Start_Date field, so I used the query:

```
 OleDbCommand myComd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(Start_Date()) AS varchar(2)), 2) 'Day'],[MONTH(Start_Date()) 'Month'], [Event_Title], [Event_Time] FROM tblEvents", con);
```

But it's showing an error.

Comment: If I remember well, RIGHT, DAY, MONTH are VBA functions and are not available when you use OleDb

Comment: then how to do this for oledb, have any idea

Comment: Not sure if you could bypass this limitation but you could try to create a query in your access db then call it from oledb passing parameters and defining the CommantType to be a StoredProcedure.

Comment: You don't tell us what the error is saying? We need to see the error. Also, your SQL statement has incorrect syntax. I suggest you look to get the SQL correct.

Comment: Check out DATEPART for DAY, MONTH replacements